# How do i load content from a seperate .php/html file into a div with jQuery .append and window.location?

Tags: php, jquery, append, window.location

I've just finished my first website using some jQuery and now im trying to figure out how to add content to my .content div using jquery.
I'm trying to use this code but it's obviously not correct.
Basically i think having seperate files with content in them might be best, then load ".append()" them into the div using jQuery. How do i do this?
I'm using this code now:

```
    <div class="content"></div>

    $('#about').click(function() {
    $('.module1').show(600);
    $('.content').animate({'width':'620'},600);
    $('.content').append(
    window.location.href("about.php")
    );
```

Comment: `$('.content').append("about.php")` should work. why are you adding `window.location.href` in between?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.post()` to load content from your php

```
$('#about').click(function () {
    $('.module1').show(600);
    $('.content').animate({
        'width': '620'
    }, 600);

    $.post('about.php', function (data) {
        $('.content').append(data);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried the code but it isn't working, chrome inspect element network XHR error. Same error occurs if i swap the about.php file for a one line test.txt file.

Comment: I've even tried doing  $(".content").load("test.txt"); but that doesnt work either, could my CSS on .content be getting in the way or what?

Comment: Figured it out! The XHR error i was getting (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) was because i wasnt running this on a test server, i loaded the site onto xampp and its working now!